# API para subir archivos en PHP

Tags: php, upload

Que tal gente,

Estoy buscando un API/Framework PHP que permita subir archivos a un servidor web de manera segura (no quiero un defacement en mi sitio), estoy usando PHP, HTML, AngularJS, Bootstrap.

Si conocen alguno que me pueda ayudar y que la licencia no sea de pago les agradecería dejarlo aquí abajo, Gracias.

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando recomendaciones para APis/manuales/libros se basan principalmente en opiniones y suelen acabar cerradas porque no se ajustan bien al formato del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar un formulario seguro y que la información que suban a tu servidor no ponga en riesgo.

Puedes validar las extensiones de los archivos que suben a tu sitio utilizando la variable global `$_FILES["codigo"]` .

Los códigos de error que puede devolver `$_FILES[‘mi_archivo’][‘error’]` son:

1. El fichero seleccionado excede el tamaño máximo permitido en php.ini (podemos saber el tamaño máximo permitido usando la función `ini_get(‘upload_max_filesize’)`).
2. El archivo subido excede la directiva `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, si se especificó en el formulario.
3. El archivo subido fue sólo parcialmente cargado.
4. No se ha subido ningún archivo.
5. Falta el directorio de almacenamiento temporal.
6. No se puede escribir el archivo (posible problema relacionado con los permisos de escritura).

Con este código puedes verificar que tipo de archivos permites que suban a tu servidor:

```
<?php
//tomo el valor de un elemento de tipo texto del formulario 
$cadenatexto = $_POST["cadenatexto"]; 
echo "Escribió en el campo de texto: " . $cadenatexto . "<br><br>"; 

//datos del arhivo 
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; 
$tipo_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['type']; 
$tamano_archivo = $_FILES['userfile']['size']; 
//compruebo si las características del archivo son las que deseo 
if (!((strpos($tipo_archivo, "gif") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "jpeg")) && ($tamano_archivo < 100000))) { 
    echo "La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta. <br><br><table><tr><td><li>Se permiten archivos .gif o .jpg<br><li>se permiten archivos de 100 Kb máximo.</td></tr></table>"; 
}else{ 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $nombre_archivo)){ 
        echo "El archivo ha sido cargado correctamente."; 
    }else{ 
        echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse."; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

También te recomendaría uses un [captcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php) en tu formulario.

Una recomendación adicional para olvidarte un poco de este tipo de problemas utiliza un framework de desarrollo como [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) por ejemplo que hacen énfasis en la seguridad, nada es 100% seguro pero te va ayudar mucho.

Saludos

Comment: @quevedo desde revisión: Hacer uso de ella crea graves problemas de seguridad. Permite intrusión en el sistema de archivos e incluso ejecución de código malicioso. La validación de extensiones no es segura ni recomendable. Y, el mecanismo de guardado preserva los nombres ofrecidos por el usuario, hecho que vulnera las normativas de seguridad mínimas. Hay más problemas de éste orden pero se me acaba el espacio para enumerarlos.

Comment: Es importante lo que comenta Alvar,o puedes tener **graves problemas de seguridad** @StivenTriana

Comment: Ya se controla en el código que solo se suban archivos con ciertas extensiones, hay que complementar que no permitan archivos .php .exe ,etc. Con eso se controlaría la seguridad.

Comment: Por experiencia: desde HTML se puede invocar un archivo .jpg como si fuera un .js y se ejecutará el código. Comprobar la extensión del fichero subido es una medida débil de seguridad que debe ser complementada con otras.

Comment: Por supuesto no digo que sea la unica pero es una medida que se debe realizar.